# При дебаге многопоточного приложения все потоки останавливаются?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть цикл в котором по коллекции `Parallel.ForEach` в которой `N` элементов.

Когда я вхожу в цикл, то вижу в списке Task `M` задач, когда попадаю на точку останова. Далее делаю шаг и остается только `1` задача.

Такое впечатление, что приостанавливается только текущая задача (которая дебажится), а остальные выполняются.

Это нормально? Мне всегда казалось, что абсолютно все потоки приостанавливаются.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь написано, что все потоки останавливаются

> Хорошо, кажется, что всякий раз, когда вы попадаете в точку останова
>   процесса, все потоки в этом процессе останавливаются, и, похоже, нет
>   никакого способа переопределить это поведение.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466835/keep-secondary-threads-running-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/#28790478

Но когда вы делаете шаг, другие потоки тоже запускаются. Чтобы другие потоки не запускались можно сделать так:

> В окне "Threads" (Debug -> Windows -> Threads) щелкните правой кнопкой
>   мыши нужный поток и выберите "switch to thread".
>
> Вы также можете выбрать "freeze" на потоках, которые Вы не хотите
>   отлаживать, чтобы удержать их от работы. Однако не забудьте "thaw"
>   их, если вы ожидаете, что они будут работать.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901736/visual-studio-debug-one-of-multiple-threads/#3901746

Comment: Ужасный перевод)

Comment: @Yami: Если можете улучшить, улучшайте! Видите ссылку "править" внизу вопроса?

Comment: Если все потоки останавливаются, то разве не должны задачи синхронно выполняться(или околосинхронно)? А тут сделал шаг и бамс все задачи выполнились.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вы можете добавить точку останова в метод, который вызывает другой поток и посмотреть в какой момент она сработает, когда делаете шаг.

Comment: Я так и делал. Только в лямбда-выражении.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вы добавили точку останова в другие Task?

Comment: Нееет. Я кажется вас понимаю. Получается, что точка останова, которые я поставил абстрагируясь от потока относится к потоку выполнения, которые присоединился к обработке параллельного цикла и торможу значит я только его в то время, как поток начнет свою работу остальные потоки могут быть выполнены

Comment: @iluxa1810 Нет, я же написал, что точка останова останавливает все потоки.

Comment: Не, я к тому, что планировщик потоков ставит потоки в очередь на выполнение и тогда, когда мой поток попадет в точку останова, другие потоки могут быть уже завершены.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вы же написали, что когда поток попадает в точку останова остается `М` задач, а после шага остается 1 задача.